# I get this error when delete object in nested in nestedset in laravel8

Tags: php, laravel, nested-sets

i get this error when delete object in nested in nestedset in laravel

> "Declaration of Kalnoy\Nestedset\BaseRelation::getRelationCountHash() should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation::getRelationCountHash($incrementJoinCount = true)

Comment: show the code which is resulting in this error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not compatible to Laravel v8.17.0
https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset/issues/479

Fork with fix
https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset/pull/478#issuecomment-737104992

Answer (score 0):

***2022 Update***

You can fix this by upgrading to `kalnoy/nestedset v6.0.0` now.

[this](https://packagist.org/packages/kalnoy/nestedset#v6.0.0) solves the problem

*composer.json*

```
"require": {
   .
   . 
   "kalnoy/nestedset": "^6.0.0",
   .
   .
}
```